# VBA IE11 locking in a change to a dropdown value

Tags: vba, excel, internet-explorer-11

I'm using VBA to open a website, login, and navigate to a certain page.  There is a dropdown with 8 options.

I used this code to change the dropdown to the value I want, but it always reverts back to the default as I continue.  How do I lock this change in?

```
Set Element = IE.Document.getElementsByName("date_range")
Element.Item(0).Value = "custom"
```

Here's the page code:

```
<div class="SelectInput">
<select class="SelectInput-select" name="date_range">
    <option value="all_time">All Time</option>
    <option value="today">Today</option>
    <option value="yesterday">Yesterday</option>
    <option value="this_month">Month to date</option>
    <option value="last_month">Last Month</option>
    <option value="this_year">Year to date</option>
    <option value="last_year">Last year</option>
    <option value="custom">Between...</option>
</select>
<div class="SelectInput-arrows">...</div>
</div>
```

Thanks,

Comment: Can you post the link to the page or something similar for testing your code?

Comment: Is this handled from the click event or are all 8 options hard coded in the HTML page?  For the first one, you may try `IE.Document.getElementById("the id you have").SelectedIndex = 0`.  For the second one, you can try `IE.Document.getElementById("the id you have").Value = "custom"`.

Comment: I can't post the link, it's behind a login page.  I added the code for that section though.  There are no element IDs, just the names

Answer (score 0):

you need to set the `selected` attribute .... ref: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_option_selected

Comment: I don't follow.  Do you have more detail?